# How to stream the media, playing in media player to other peer devices media player over WiFi?

Tags: java, android, audio, stream, android-mediaplayer

So, in my application, I want to add the functionality of local audio streaming over WiFi to connected peer devices. i'm following  [this tutorial for audio streaming over WiFi.](https://srihary.com/2014/09/06/localhttpserver-to-stream-video-files-on-android-to-other-devices/) It is working perfectly. But the issue is, I've to specify the file name and exact path which I want to stream, explicitly.

In My application, I've used `Media Store` to get music available on the users device. So there is no path available for each media item. Even if I can get exact path of each media item, the problem is to seek to the desired time. Another problem is that I've to restart all the streaming threads when one song gets completed and other song starts.

So my Idea is to stream the content of media player itself over the WiFi. So that there will be no problem of seeking or updating the threads. When host seeks to desired time, all devices will receive update automatically because we are now streaming the content of media player itself.

I've searched on Google about this, all I got is `MediaPlayer.setDataSource()` method. Which is exactly reverse of my case. Also there is no such thing mentioned in official Android documentation of `Media Player`.

For reference, I'm using the following method to get song list using media store.

```
public void getSongList() {
//retrieve song info
ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
//iterate over results if valid
if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
    //get columns
    int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
    int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
    int albumId = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
    int data= musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    int albumkey=musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_KEY);
    //add songs to list
    do {
        long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
        String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
        String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
        long thisalbumId = musicCursor.getLong(albumId);
        String thisdata= musicCursor.getString(data);
        String AlbumKey = musicCursor.getString(albumkey);
        tempSongList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisalbumId, thisdata, AlbumKey));

    }
    while (musicCursor.moveToNext());

}
}
```

I know I can get the exact path from this. [Here is the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178275/getting-audio-file-path-or-uri-from-mediastore)

But I want to stream the content of media player itself. Is it possible or not? Is there any alternatives for this functionality?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your looking for something like HLS. Read up on it.